# tensorflow tutorial of convolution, scale of logit

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

I am trying to edit my own model by adding some code to cifar10.py and here is the question.

In cifar10.py, the [tutorial][1] says:

> **EXERCISE:** The output of inference are un-normalized logits. Try editing the network architecture to return normalized predictions using tf.nn.softmax().

So I directly input the output from "local4" to `tf.nn.softmax()`. This gives me the *scaled* logits which means the sum of all logits is 1.

But in the loss function, the cifar10.py code uses:

```
tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()
```

and description of this function says

> **WARNING:** This op expects unscaled logits, since it performs a softmax on logits internally for efficiency. Do not call this op with the output of softmax, as it will produce incorrect results.

Also, according to the description, logits as input to above funtion must have the shape [batch_size, num_classes] and it means logits should be unscaled softmax, like sample code calculate unnormalized softmaxlogit as follow.

```
  # softmax, i.e. softmax(WX + b)
  with tf.variable_scope('softmax_linear') as scope:
    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', [192, NUM_CLASSES],
                                          stddev=1/192.0, wd=0.0)
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [NUM_CLASSES],
                              tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    softmax_linear = tf.add(tf.matmul(local4, weights), biases, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(softmax_linear)
```

Does this mean I don't have to use `tf.nn.softmax` in the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `tf.nn.softmax` in the code if you want, but then you will have to compute the loss yourself:

```py
softmax_logits = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(- labels * tf.log(softmax_logits) - (1. - labels) * tf.log(1. - softmax_logits))
```

---

In practice, you don't use `tf.nn.softmax` for computing the loss. However you need to use `tf.nn.softmax` if for instance you want to compute the predictions of your algorithm and compare them to the true labels (to compute accuracy).

Comment: Thanks. by the way, what is `(1. - labels) * tf.log(1. - softmax_logits)`   for? I know `- labels * tf.log(softmax_logits)` is normal cross entropy but latter part. Is this something for "sparse" things?

Comment: No, the [cross entropy loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy#Cross-entropy_error_function_and_logistic_regression) is the sum of both those terms.

Comment: Thank you, Olivier. Now I completely understood.